# slick.js - Несколько слайдеров на странице - то загружаются, то нет, и не срабатывает адаптив

Tags: slick.js, слайдер, slider-slick.js

День добрый!
На сайте используется слайдер slick. На странице располагается несколько слайдеров (каждый элемент имеет уникальный класс благодаря {$rand}), но часть из них то загружается/инициализируется, то нет (изображения размещаются просто в столбец). Для тех слайдеров, что не загружаются, в консоли появляется ошибка **$(...).slick is not a function**. Список слайдеров, которые не подгружаются, меняется. Страница с одним слайдером работает исправно.

Было предположение, что к моменту вызова слайдера не успевает создаться html-элемент, к которому применяется slick - но вывод в консоль показал, что нужный элемент уже есть. Так же на всякий случай проверила правильную последовательность подключения jQuery, js слайдера и вызова скрипта - тоже всё ок (тем более что в других случаях всё работает).

В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?
Отдельный момент - если на странице единственный слайдер, то на адаптиве он отображается корректно. Но если их несколько, то те, что правильно загрузились, не адаптируются под мобильные размеры (точнее, для высоты и ширины выставляются какие-то безумные 5-значные числа) - тоже вопрос, почему?

**UPD:**
Добавление setTimeout устранило проблему с подгрузкой всех слайдеров, хотя решение выглядит костыльным. Остальное актуально

Код скрипта, в котором подключается слайдер:

````
<script>
  {/* проверяем подключение slick.css и slick.js */}
  const checkGallary{$rand} = (teg, srcLink, typ) => {
    const arrTeg = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(teg));
    const HTMLElement = document.createElement(teg);
    if (!arrTeg.find((item) => item[typ] === srcLink)) {
      HTMLElement[typ] = srcLink;
      if (teg === 'link') {
        HTMLElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
        HTMLElement.type = 'text/css';
      }
      document.querySelector('#gal_photo-{$rand}').before(HTMLElement);
      return HTMLElement;
    }
    return null;
  }

  checkGallary{$rand}('link','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css','href');
  const resultCheckGallary{$rand} = checkGallary{$rand}('script', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js','src')
  
  if (resultCheckGallary{$rand}) {
    resultCheckGallary{$rand}.addEventListener('load', () => {
      $('.slider-for-{$rand}').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav-{$rand}',
        dots: true,
      });
      
      $('.slider-nav-{$rand}').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for-{$rand}',
        dots: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        arrows: false,
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      $('.slider-for-{$rand}').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav-{$rand}',
        dots: true,
      });

      $('.slider-nav-{$rand}').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for-{$rand}',
        dots: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        arrows: false,
      });
    }, 1000)
  }

</script> ```
````

Comment: Это как вообще: `const checkGallary{$rand}`? Что за `{$rand}`, откуда он?

Comment: `каждый элемент имеет уникальный класс благодаря {$rand}` -- так как Вы не отвечаете что такое `$rand`, предоложу что это переменная, если это так, то это не будет работать как Вы задумали, так как в переменную сохранено какое-то определенное значение и оно не поменяется при использовании со следующим элементом, только если Вы ее не переопределите. Но даже если переопределите, в приведенном коде везде будет использовано одно значение, а не разные. Предположу что это PHP, в таком случае такая конструкция работать не будет `checkGallary{$rand}` и все остальное по типу `'.slider-for-{$rand}'`.

Comment: Действительно, это переменная Smarty, она генерируется и работает корректно, в т.ч. в других местах сайта.

Comment: Теперь стало немного понятнее. У Вас опечатка перед закрывающей скобкой `else`, `}, 500)` и я не совсем понимаю смысл `if/else` в этом случае как таковой. Я локально немного отформатировал код, до этого думал что Вы там просто 4 слика инитите.

Comment: О, это я в последний момент убрала одну команду, а ее вторую часть забыла удалить, спасибо! И да, извиняюсь за форматирование - этот код достался "свыше" и я постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что он неотформатирован, потому уже как-то забила и привыкла и не обращала внимание, пока вы не сказали) Чуть привела в порядок и заменила